# What is the difference between squaring a negative number inside and outside of parentheses?

Tags: exponentiation

What is the difference between:
$
-3^2
$
and
$
(-3)^2
$
?
I know $-3^2 = -9$ and $(-3)^2 = 9$ but I don't know why.

Comment: -3^2 = -1*3*3 = -9

Comment: (-3)^2 = -3*-3 = 9

Comment: Because when you $-3^2$ you're not squaring -ve sign here. But when you use parentheses you square -ve sign as well.

Comment: $-3^2 = (-1) \cdot 3^2 = (-1) \cdot 9 = -9\,$ because exponentiation has higher precedence than multiplication.

Comment: Related: [What is the accepted syntax for a negative number with an exponent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382664)

Comment: $(-3)^2=((-1)(3))^2=(-1)^2\cdot (3)^2=9$ while $-3^2=-(3)^2=-9$

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of the order of operations.

If you write $-3^{2}$, you're saying "the square of 3, now make it negative" = "9, now make it negative" = "-9".

If you write $(-3)^{2}$, you're saying "make 3 negative, now square it" = "-3, now square it" = "(-3)(-3)" = "9".

Answer (score 0):

So by convention, the power operation has higher priority than multiply operation unless you have "$()$" to indicate priority.

$$-3^2=-1\times 3^2=-1\times 3\times 3$$

While

$$(-3)^2=(-3)\times (-3)=(-1\times 3)\times (-1\times 3) = -1\times -1 \times 3\times 3$$